# How to add a layout with the click of button and id each element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-contacts, viewgroup

Here is my image

[image: Here is my image]

[image]

How can i add a new layout PROGRAMATICALLY(with a button and an EditText)on CLICK of a '+' button and set a unique id for each child(like in the pic).

Comment: you need to read Android Fundamental...

Comment: i know android fundamental buddy..im akin how i can inflate a viewgroup and then assign a unique id to each element

Comment: but in question you ask about how to add new layout with button and edittext. it's very simple...

Comment: yes adding a button and textview on clicking '+' button...sorry if the question was confusing

Comment: Edit your question correctly...Good question always get good Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private Button buttonItemArray[] = new Button[50];
private EditText edtValueArray[] = new EditText[50];


            int itemId = itemCounter;
            int valueId = valueCounter;

            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(
                    getApplicationContext());
            linearLayout.setOrientation(0);

            buttonItemArray[j] = new Button(NewVendorDetailActivity.this);
            buttonItemArray[j].setLayoutParams(edtName.getLayoutParams());
            buttonItemArray[j].setId(itemId);
            buttonItemArray[j].setText(name);

                    edtValueArray[j] = new EditText(NewVendorDetailActivity.this);
        edtValueArray[j].setLayoutParams(edtName.getLayoutParams());
        edtValueArray[j].setId(valueId);
           edtValueArray[j].setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.editbox_background_normal);
        edtValueArray[j].setSingleLine(true);
        edtValueArray[j].setText(value);

        linearLayout.addView(txtItemArray[j]);
        linearLayout.addView(edtValueArray[j]);



            layout.addView(linearLayout);
            itemCounter++;
            valueCounter++;
            j++;
```

try this type add button custom ..........

Comment: this one code written in your add button click  and one more your xml in add blank layout

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following,

http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

create a button in xml 
            
and in Activity call the xml like this
Button contacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contacts);
and then create a onclick listener for button 
contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Contacts.Intents.Insert.ACTION,
                    Contacts.People.CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
            intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, entryname);
            intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, phone);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```